# Fatal error: Declaration of .. must be compatible with .. PHP (parameter required: extended class of specification)

Tags: php, interface, parameter-passing, abstract, extends

I'm working on the next version of my language-constraint reconciliation system. I started with this (the `abstract` function declaration seems to be the problem):

```
namespace AAABIT;
abstract class LangPrefSet{
    private $LangPrefs;
    public function __construct(){$this->LangPrefs=array();}
    public function add(LangPref $langpref){$this->LangPrefs[]=$langpref;}
    public function langPrefs(){return $this->LangPrefs;}
    abstract public function reconcile(LangPrefSet $other);//←Seems to be throwing an error… We don't strictly need this line, but this is a little concerning…
    protected static function reconcile_LangPrefSets(LangPrefSet_ForUser $UserLangPrefSet,LangPrefSet_Resource $RsrcLangPrefSet,$maxOptions){//…
    }
}
//Following classes are necessary because language similarity is a one-way mapping. Just because resources in Lang A (e.g. Russian) are likely to be readily understandable for speakers/readers of Lang B (e.g. Ukrainian), does not mean that the resources in Lang B (e.g. Ukrainian) are equally intelligible for speakers/readers of Lang A (e.g. Russian)!
class LangPrefSet_For_User extends LangPrefSet{public function reconcile(LangPrefSet_Resource $RsrcLangPrefSet){return self::reconcile_LangPrefSets(self,$RsrcLangPrefSet);}}
class LangPrefSet_Resource extends LangPrefSet{public function reconcile(LangPrefSet_For_User $UserLangPrefSet){return self::reconcile_LangPrefSets($UserLangPrefSet,self);}}
```

I thought this would work because LangPrefSet_Resource conforms to LangPrefSet; but PHP found this objectionable, throwing the aforementioned error. I thought I might have better luck with an Interface… So I did this:

```
interface LangPrefSet_Reconcilable{
    public function reconcile(LangPrefSet_Reconcilable $other);
}
```

Then I made the two classes extending LangPrefSet, `implements LangPrefSet_Reconcilable`, and commented out the abstract function declaration (after first trying to make that require an `LangPrefSet_Reconcilable` interface-typed parameter, also which didn't work) — the results are:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of AAABIT\LangPrefSet_For_User::reconcile() must be compatible with AAABIT\LangPrefSet_Reconcilable::reconcile(AAABIT\LangPrefSet_Reconcilable $other)
```

— This is not a blocker issue for me, since I can just strip out the `abstract function` and `interface` and the system will work fine. However I'm concerned that I might not have understood interfaces/ abstract classes properly!

What is wrong with specifying that a class method overriding `abstract function a(ObjB $b)` or a similar interface specification, takes as a parameter `ObjC $c`, where ObjC extends ObjB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue may to be that in the abstract class declaration, I am specifying that **any** `LangPrefSet` must be acceptable to the `reconcile()` object method:

```
abstract public function reconcile(LangPrefSet $other);
```

— Whereas in the actual method declaration, I am specifying in one case that **only** a `LangPrefSet_Resource` would be acceptable, and in the other case, that **only** a `LangPrefSet_For_User` would be acceptable.

*The object method declarations are therefore incompatible with the abstract method declaration*. It seems that the proper application of these interface/abstract method declaration techniques is not to broaden the range of permissible parameter type constraints in classes that implement the interface, since we may achieve this simply by declaring the input restrictions as they ought to be for those specific classes/methods; but rather, interface/abstract method declarations are meant to broaden the range of parameters that may actually be passed to a method that specifies these abstract parameter types.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter type must be the same in the interface(or abstract class) and where you are implementing the same. right now the interface is `LangPrefSet_Reconcilable`
and the implementation says `LangPrefSet_Resource` and `LangPrefSet_For_User`.

You can either use a 2nd interface like below, or use the same class.

```
interface LangPrefSetReconcilableDataInteface {
    ...
}

interface LangPrefSet_Reconcilable{
    public function reconcile(LangPrefSetReconcilableDataInteface $other);
}

class LangPrefSet_Resource implements LangPrefSetReconcilableDataInteface {
...
}

class LangPrefSet_For_User implements LangPrefSetReconcilableDataInteface {
...
}

class LangPrefSet_For_User extends LangPrefSet
{
    public function reconcile(LangPrefSetReconcilableDataInteface $RsrcLangPrefSet)
    {
        return self::reconcile_LangPrefSets(self,$RsrcLangPrefSet);
    }
}

class LangPrefSet_Resource extends LangPrefSet
{
    public function reconcile(LangPrefSetReconcilableDataInteface $UserLangPrefSet)
    {
        return self::reconcile_LangPrefSets($UserLangPrefSet,self);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by his because you appear to be redeclaring classes.
Regarding your solution with two interfaces, does it have to be this convoluted? As mentioned in my question, this is not a blocker issue for me: I tend to favour beautiful code that is easily maintained, modified and upgraded. With the interfaces/ abstract method declarations, I'm trying to make sure that appropriate errors are thrown if anyone tries to change something in an inadvisable way: if the implementation for this "icing on the cake" is inscrutable at first glance, I might just leave it out!