I'm getting a fatal error on my wordpress site
Fatal error, can't figure out how to fix! Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Fatal error: Declaration of Walker_CategoryDropdown_Custom::start_el(&$output, $category, $depth, $args) must be compatible with Walker_CategoryDropdown::start_el(&$output, $data_object, $depth = 0, $args = [], $current_object_id = 0) in /home/chrispapuga1/public_html/wp-content/themes/automotive/functions.php on line 877

Here is line 877:
function start_el(&$output , $category , $depth , $args)

I tried typing in the recommended text as shown in the error (start_el(&$output, $data_object, $depth = 0, $args = [], $current_object_id = 0), which produced more errors! Here is the full script (lines 875-895):
class Walker_CategoryDropdown_Custom extends Walker_CategoryDropdown
        {
            function start_el(&$output , $category , $depth , $args)
            {
                $pad = str_repeat(' ' , $depth * 3);

                $cat_name = apply_filters('list_cats' , $category->name , $category);
                $output .= "\t<option class=\"level-$depth\" value=\"" . $category->name . "\" data-value=\"" . $category->term_id . "\"";
                if ( $category->term_id == $args[ 'selected' ] ) $output .= ' selected="selected"';
                $output .= '>';
                $output .= $pad . $cat_name;
                if ( $args[ 'show_count' ] ) $output .= '  (' . $category->count . ')';
                if ( array_key_exists('show_last_update', $args) && $args[ 'show_last_update' ] ) {
                    $format = 'Y-m-d';
                    $output .= '  ' . gmdate($format , $category->last_update_timestamp);
                }
                $output .= "</option>\n";

            }

        }


Well you are missing the last parameter for starters $current_object_id

Does this answer your question? Fatal error: Declaration of .. must be compatible with .. PHP

Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847300/fatal-error-declaration-of-must-be-compatible-with-php-parameter-require

RiggsFolly- I added that parameter in, saved the changes, and received more errors, so I have set it back to the way it was.

Maybe you've received other errors? Also, if this is some kind of Wordpress plugin, maybe it needs an update?

change line 877 to function start_el(&$output, $category, $depth, $args, $current_object_id = 0)
